# I got this MSG when trying to delete from db table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When Trying to delete from the db table through CodeIgniter

```
$id=$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->delete('rewards',$id);
```

i got this error msg

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Illegal offset
>   type Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 402

I do not know the reason of this error, any help?

Comment: I just looked at the documentation. The way codeigniter works is that you are building the query when you call `$this->db->where()`. So you need to do `$this->db->where('id', $id); $this->db->delete('rewards');` instead of what you are currently doing. Here is the documentation... http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that is on line 402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to delete record in wrong way.
Proper way to delete is:

```
$id = 123;    
$this->db->delete('mytable', array('id' => $id));
```